# No source has been specified while using CSVLoader

Tags: java

In my Java code I am trying to read a `.csv` file into a `.arff` file and I am making use of `CSVLoader` for this purpose. Below is my code :

```
package processingPackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;


public class GenerateArffDetails {

    /*filePath in the following line*/
    /*"/Users/SubrataMohanty/Desktop/customer_loan_details.csv"*/
    public String getTrainFilePath (String filePath) throws IOException {

            System.out.println(filePath);
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File(filePath));

            System.out.println(filePath);
            Instances dataStructure = loader.getStructure();
            Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

            weka.core.converters.ArffSaver saver = new weka.core.converters.ArffSaver();

            saver.setInstances(data);
            saver.setFile(new File("/Users/SubrataMohanty/Desktop/customer_loan_details.arff"));
            saver.writeBatch();

            String path = "/Users/SubrataMohanty/Desktop/customer_loan_details.arff";
            return (path);
        }
}
```

Upon executing the above code, I keep getting the following error trace.

```
java.io.IOException: No source has been specified
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getStructure(CSVLoader.java:962)
    at processingPackage.GenerateArffDetails.getTrainFilePath(GenerateArffDetails.java:19)
    at processingPackage.LoanClassifier.classifyLoanApplicant(LoanClassifier.java:23)
    at processingPackage.Driver.classifyApplicants(Driver.java:15)
    at processingPackage.RunClassifier.doGet(RunClassifier.java:38)
    at processingPackage.RunClassifier.doPost(RunClassifier.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I pass the filePath variable in the following String variable format :

```
"/Users/SubrataMohanty/Desktop/customer_loan_details.csv"
```

Upon doing a further reading on the `CSVLoader` class I stumbled up the m_sourceReader variable which is initialized like this :

```
m_sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

and returns the exception above if it has **null** which I do not understand as I am clearly passing a `filePath` which is correct. So what is my error?

May I know how to resolve this?

**NOTE :** I am working on MacOSX Sierra for my project.

Comment: Put the `new File(filePath)` in a new line and check what's in there - is it as expected?

Comment: Yes, the m_sourceReader variable refuses to take a value, hence the exception. @yishaiz

Comment: So debug the code of CSVLoader, its not much, for what goes wrong in the way. For example, it uses `AbstractFileLoader.setSource` along the way which does `fName = m_env.substitute(fName);`. Also try to use `loader.setSource(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It was a really basic error I was making with respect to double quotes around my path @yishaiz

Comment: Glad it worked out :) consider adding your solution as an answer, in case other people will encounter this.

Comment: Pls @AbhijeetMohanty how did you resolve this. I don't understand your last comment.